# using TableHTMLExport, how can i tell it to ignore certain divs and spans?

Tags: javascript, jquery, export

I am using
https://github.com/FuriosoJack/TableHTMLExport

I've got a rather complicated table with lots of hidden elements and I wanted a way to export this table using the said plugin. It works fine actually except it's also exporting all the hidden elements (style = display: hidden)

I've gone through the docs and I can't find the options for this.

All I could come up with is this:

```js
$("#myTable").tableHTMLExport({
    type: 'csv',
    htmlContent: false,
    filename: filename_csv,
    ignoreColumns: '.export_ignore_col',
    ignoreRows: '.export_ignore_row'
});
```

Comment: Hi , did you tried below code ?

Answer (score 1):

*Alternative way* :

You can read there documentation there is codepen [link](https://codepen.io/furiosojack/pen/JmyExX?editors=1111) you can edit this code to achieve above . In below code i have made changes inside `toCsv` function .First i have check if the `td` or `th` has `children` and if the `length > 0` then  i have loop through `childrens` node and have check if they are `visible` or not depending on this i have appended `value` inside `output` variable.

***Demo Code***(with dummy datas) :

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    tableHTMLExport: function(options) {

      var defaults = {
        separator: ',',
        newline: '\r\n',
        ignoreColumns: '',
        ignoreRows: '',
        type: 'csv',
        htmlContent: false,
        consoleLog: false,
        trimContent: true,
        quoteFields: true,
        filename: 'tableHTMLExport.csv',
        utf8BOM: true,
        charSet: 'utf-8',
        orientation: 'p' //only when exported to *pdf* "portrait" or "landscape" (or shortcuts "p" or "l")
      };
      var options = $.extend(defaults, options);


      function quote(text) {
        return '"' + text.replace('"', '""') + '"';
      }


      function parseString(data) {

        if (defaults.htmlContent) {
          content_data = data.html().trim();
        } else {
          content_data = data.text().trim();
        }
        return content_data;
      }

      function download(filename, text) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=' + options.charSet + ',' + encodeURIComponent(text));
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);

        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.click();

        document.body.removeChild(element);
      }



      /**
       * Convierte la tabla enviada a csv o texto
       * @param table
       * @returns {string}
       */
      function toCsv(table) {
        var output = "";

        if (options.utf8BOM === true) {
          output += '\ufeff';
        }
        var rows = table.find('tr').not(options.ignoreRows);
        var numCols = rows.first().find("td,th").not(options.ignoreColumns).length;

        rows.each(function() {
          $(this).find("td,th").not(options.ignoreColumns)
            .each(function(i, col) {
              var column = $(col);
              //check if td or th has children .ie. : any div or span..etc
              if ($(col).children().length > 0) {
                //loop through it
                $(col).children().each(function() {
                  //check if the element is visible(not hidden)
                  if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    //append them inside output variable
                    output += $(this).text();
                  }
                })

              } else {
                // Strip whitespaces
                var content = options.trimContent ? $.trim(column.text()) : column.text();

                output += options.quoteFields ? quote(content) : content;
              }
              if (i !== numCols - 1) {
                output += options.separator;
              } else {
                output += options.newline;
              }
            });
        });
        console.log(" Output >>> " + output)
        return output;
      }


      var el = this;
      var dataMe;
      if (options.type == 'csv' || options.type == 'txt') {


        var table = this.filter('table'); // TODO use $.each

        if (table.length <= 0) {
          throw new Error('tableHTMLExport must be called on a <table> element')
        }

        if (table.length > 1) {
          throw new Error('converting multiple table elements at once is not supported yet')
        }

        dataMe = toCsv(table);

        if (defaults.consoleLog) {
          console.log(dataMe);
        }
        download(options.filename, dataMe);

      }
      return this;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$("#tableCompany").tableHTMLExport({
  type: 'csv',
  filename: 'soemthingss.csv',
  ignoreColumns: '.acciones,#primero',
  ignoreRows: ''
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.5.3/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@3.2.3/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>


<table id="tableCompany">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contactt</th>
      <th class='acciones'>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Alfreds Futterkiste </span>
        <div style="display:none">cdcdcdcdci</div>
        <div>sti</div>
      </td>
      <td id="primero">Maria Anders</td>
      <td class="acciones">Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Ernst Handel </span>
        <div style="display:none">cdi</div>
        <div>soemthinss</div>
      </td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td class="acciones">Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Island Trading </span>
        <div style="display:none">tr</div>
      </td>
      <td><span>Helen Bennett </span>
        <div style="display:none">tr</div>
        <div>twew</div>
      </td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```